# Understanding function self-referencing mechanics

Tags: javascript, function

I had (approximately) this situation: I was trying to declare `func1()` function  and add couple of static methods to it in one go by running it through `_init()` function providing a hash with properties to attach to it, not being aware of that it didn't remain declared in current scope after `_init()` function did it's job. It just got temporarily defined, and gc-ed after `_init()` run (as far as I'm aware). Here's the code sample:

```
//
// #_init
// merge src{} into target{}, overwriting
// 
var _init = (function (target, src) {

  var _ = this;

  if (_.isobj(target))
    _.keys(src).forEach(_.pass, {
      src    : src, 
      target : target
    });

  return target;

}).bind({

  isobj : (function (node) {
    return node === this(node);
  }).bind(Object), 

  keys  : (function (node) {
    return this.keys(this(node));
  }).bind(Object), 

  pass  : function (field) {
    this.target[field] = this.src[field];
  }

});
```

, and I was hoping to 'batch-init' it here adding static methods at the same time:

```
_init(function func1 (e) {
  var _api = func1.pop(arguments);
  var node = this;
  // and stuff...
}, {
  pop: Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.pop), 
  // ...etc
});
```

When trying to reference it later I got error:

```
x = func1();
// ReferenceError: func1 is not defined
// x = func1()
```

Assigning the output of `_init()` to `var func2` does the job, I can reference and use the function. Thing that confuses me is when `console.log()`-ing the `func2` logs 'func1()', but trying to refernce `func1` directly throws ReferenceError:

```
//
// #func2
//
var func2 = _init(function func1 () {
  return func1.pop(arguments);
}, {
  pop: Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.pop)
});

console.log(typeof func2, func2, func2(1,2,3));
// function func1() 3

console.log(func1(1,2,3));
// ReferenceError: func1 is not defined
// console.log(func1(1,2,3));
//
```

Could someone explain to me why the `func1` reference didn't get created, but (strangely) was availble to `func2` (it obviously was able to use it...)?

Comment: There are so many errors here it's not possible to tell. You should step down in a first time, and focus on more simple construct or find a lib that will handle the inheritance and such things for you.

Comment: could you elaborate more on that, what errors, simple construct?

Comment: It looks like an extremely complicated way to do something that doesn't sound that complicated. Figure out what you want to do, start with *simple* functions, and try to keep it as simple as possible, as it's very hard to follow the way you're passing functions and binding entire objects to an IIFE that then returns the function etc.

Comment: "it's not possible to tell" means i won't elaborate.

Comment: @adeneo: it's just the matter of speeding things up... Avoiding identifier lookup outside of function's scope by stuffing the data in function scope improves the execution speed in my experience.

Comment: @nikolav: Wow, no, it just complicates everything you do. And please notice the difference between the variable scope, and the call `this` context. Identifier resolution (even in parent scopes) is incredibly fast, property lookups not so much. You should test it.

Comment: @GameAlchemist: So many errors? There is only one, related to the NFE, the rest works fine. Please elaborate what else you see. That the design pattern is not best practice is clear, but that's no error.

Comment: @Bergi : come on, the whole thing is a joke...

Comment: @GameAlchemist: I don't think so, the code is quite straight-forward from an uncommon perspective. But if you see it as a joke then I understand your comment…

Comment: I'm not fulling around with this question, it's just that I wasn't aware of how function declaration vs. function expressions worked. I've apparently mixed up those two. + to Bergi's answer.

Comment: @Bergi: _notice the difference between the variable scope, and the call this context_ 
 Would you please be more specific about the _variable scope_ vs. _this_ (a.k.a. scope, a.k.a. context)? I figure the variable scopes are implemented as tree structres of tables holding their names and what they point to, right? And scope is the thing (an object) the function is found in (and referenced with _this_ keyword).

Comment: I've figured out the NFE-NFD difference you've mentioned and linked to. `func1` would be available for direct reference had I _declared_ it previously somewhere, basically creating a variable initialised to function object. 

I don't see how scopes are wrong if I understood your comment corectly. `_init`'s scope is 'locked' to bound object and cannot be manipulated via `.call`, `.apply` methods, and `func1`'s scope stays dynamic, I can set it to whatever is needed, or use it as event handler, etc.

Comment: No, the `this` object thing that a function is called on is the *context*, not the "scope". Many people seem to get this wrong. The term "scope" should only refer to the *variable scope*.

Comment: oh, I took them as meaning the same thing, and often came across people using them as synonyms in technical literature out there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could someone explain to me why the func1 reference didn't get created, but (strangely) was availble to func2 (it obviously was able to use it...)?

That's just how [named function expressions](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/) work. Their name (`func1`) is available *inside* the function body as an identifier, but not outside. What happens to the result of the expression (passing the created function to `_init`, then assigning it to `func2`) is a different and completely unrelated thing.

---

> I was trying to declare func1() function and add couple of static methods to it

You shouldn't, unless those static methods are really supposed to be public and not just simple helper methods. Use the revealing XY pattern (IEFE) and just get your utility functions in the closure scope:

```
var _init = (function() {
  function isobj(node) {
    return node === Object(node);
  }
  function pass(field) {
    this.target[field] = this.src[field];
  }
  var keys = Object.keys;

  return function (target, src) {
    if (isobj(target))
      keys(src).forEach(_.pass, {
        src    : src, 
        target : target
      });
    return target;
  };
});
var func2 = (function() {
  var pop = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.pop);

  return function func1 () {
    return pop(arguments);
  };
});
```